# Eclipse Git Team Provider missing while installing EGit on Eclipse Oxygen?

Tags: java, eclipse, git, egit

I have been installing few packages on Eclipse Oxygen, with EGit being one of them.

First I put did ***Windows > Preferences > Available software sites > Add*** and added EGit with the link *http://download.eclipse.org/egit/updates*.

Then I went on to ***Help > Install New Software...*** and selected EGit from the list. I am required to install "**Eclipse Git Team Provider**" from the list of modules but, I can find only these (see screenshot). Why?

[image]

And, if there is any of its equivalent, which is it?

Comment: Required by whom? "Git integration for Eclipse" is what you're actually looking for.

Answer (score 1):

To install EGit, select ***Git integration for Eclipse > Git integration for Eclipse*** and if Mylyn is installed also *Git integration for Eclipse > Git integration for Eclipse - Task focused interface*.

For better usability, project names such as [EGit](http://eclipse.org/egit) (***Git integration for Eclipse*; former named: *Eclipse Git Team Provider***), [JGit](http://eclipse.org/jgit) (*Java Implementation of Git*) or [Buildship](http://eclipse.org/buildship) (*Gradle*) are not used in the user interface.